# I am trying to make an scrollable keyboard for my calculator but its not working

Tags: android, xml

I am Making a Scientific calculator with a scrollable keyboard but it didn't working same as I thing this should work

I make 2 Grid layout with 16 buttons each
I add both GridLayout in the horizontal Scroll View

I want if I scroll, all 16 button in gridlayout 1 should scroll at the same time
and grid layout 2 16 button will come to there place

This is the XML file that I create I didn't do anything in java file

```css
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="438dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="431dp"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="436dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="99dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="99dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="99dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="99dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="451dp"
        android:layout_height="397dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="3"
                app:layout_row="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_row="3" />


        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
        
        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button22"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button23"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button24"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button25"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button26"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button27"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button28"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button29"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button30"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button31"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button32"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button33"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button34"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_row="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button35"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button36"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button37"
                android:layout_width="107dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_column="3"
                app:layout_row="3" />
        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ConstraintLayout>
```